# Does FTP have Auth SSL option?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, sftp

I am working with a supplier who's just tightened their security. They moved from an anonymous FTP setup to a more secure alternative. The parameters they gave me

```
Host: blahblah.net
Port: 4421
Path: /mailbox
User: (...)
Password: (...)
Auth SSL: yes
Passive mode: yes
```

Using `ftp -pn blahblah.net 4421` allows me to connect but it hangs. I need to specify the "Auth SSL" option in my command line (and script) but how do I do that?

I read the ftp man page of my host and found nothing. I looked at using `sftp` instead but it seems that the latter does not use passive mode.

My host info
Linux 2.6.18-128.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Which operating system?  I would assume *nix, but you never know.

Comment: OS is x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [ftp-ssl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=ftp-ssl) or [lftp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=lftp) (there are others) for an FTP client with SSL/TLS support.

> looked at using sftp instead but it seems that the latter does not use passive mode.

`sftp` transfers files over encrypted ssh, where as `ftp` is a completely different protocol.

Comment: I won't pretend to understand the intricacies of FTP vs SFTP. In short, there is no other way but to install software, correct?

Comment: @Chris correct.  Ubuntu does not install a console ftp client with ssl/tls support by default.